# Do plexus annotations work in a maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, plexus

I'm working on a custom maven plugin and I'm trying to use the Plexus annotations for dependency injection as shown on the [Sonotype blog](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/05/plexus-container-five-minute-tutorial/).

I have a field defined in my mojo:

```
/**
 */
@Requirement(hint = "rhino")
private RhinoRunner rhinoRunner;
```

And the class defined with the `@Component` annotation:

```
/**
 */
@Component(role = RhinoRunner.class, hint = "rhino")
public class RhinoRunnerImpl implements RhinoRunner {
```

I then added the configuration to the components.xml.  When I use the plugin the `rhinoRunner` field is null.  If I change to use the old javadoc taglet on the dependency, like follows, it works correctly:

```
/**
 * @component
 */
private RhinoRunner rhinoRunner;
```

Is it possible to make the Java5 annotations work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin annotations differ from the plexus annotations (though the plugin annotations happen to use the same mechanism to fulfil a requirement).

You should continue to use the plugin annotations in a Mojo, but feel free to use the other annotation in pure components (in the plugin or any supporting libraries).